# Capture picture on voice command android

Tags: android, android-camera, voice-recognition

I have created a small app which has opens up a camera . I now want the picture to be taken when the user says 'Click'.

I know I need to use a Voice recognition approach. But not really sure how do I go ahead with it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, having the idea is one thing, the implementation is even harder. You don't even have any idea. You know what I want to say?

Comment: @ZerO I appreciate your rudeness.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rudeness. But you have not shown any effort in how you want to realize your speech recognition. You imagine it to be so much easier than it really is. Show us some effort, and we can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it can listen for speech command offline and perform arbitrary action when command occurs. It can take photo for example. Taking a photo is pretty easy, see documentation for details:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: I can take a picture normally and even set it to a Bitmap. I want to carry out this whole procedure with the user's voice

Comment: If you can take the picture already then the procedure is 2 very simple steps - 1) take pocketsphinx demo linked above and 2) modify it to run your capture code when word is detected.